# Jquery Ajax twitter/facebook profile images and http 302

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, twitter, http-status-code-302

So, I've read a couple things about jquery ajax and http 302 both here on stack overflow and other sites. Some places seem to say that it's an unfixable problem, others provide solutions that don't work for me (I think they might be changing some server-side scripts). I, however, am looking for a solution to fix the ajax/redirect issue with servers that I can't access... facebook and twitter!

Here's my issue.  I need to grab profile images from both facebook and twitter at a size other than their default sizes (fb- 50x50px, twitter- 48x48px).  With facebook, this is done with

https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture?type=[size]

with twitter it's

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/[screenname].json?size=[size]

both of these return an HTTP 302 redirect, which then doesn't give anything to jquery.

I tried success, error and complete to see if at some point I could grab the location of the response header and pass that through, but using the console and doing a bit of research, I found out that the browser, upon receiving a 302, according to the w3c standards, is supposed to immediately process the redirect, leaving jquery unable to get anything from the headers.

I have to do this all in javascript because with the number of people passing through the site, our server won't be able to go grab those images and pass them through to the client side. Basically, we need to make sure all the work is done by the facebook/twitter servers.

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions! :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you doing anything with Ajax?  Can't you just build an image tag, which means the client doesn't have to do two requests anyway?

```
var pUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/picture?type=[size]';
// update Url with user info & requested size.
$('#placeholder').html('<img src="' + pUrl + '" />');
```

Comment: You, sir, are the best! I think I'd been staring at ajax stuff for so long that when I read "json" in the docs I just kindof automatically went "oh. more ajax..."
Can't believe I missed something so obvious!
*high 5*